# Intersection of two lists, keeping duplicates in the first list

Tags: python, duplicates, array-intersect

I have two flat lists where one of them contains duplicate values.
For example,

```
array1 = [1,4,4,7,10,10,10,15,16,17,18,20]
array2 = [4,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I need to find values in array1 that are also in array2, KEEPING THE DUPLICATES in array1.
Desired outcome will be

```
result = [4,4,7,10,10,10]
```

I want to avoid loops as actual arrays will contain over millions of values.
I have tried various set and intersect combinations, but just couldn't keep the duplicates..

Comment: you can't avoid loops.. if you use library functions.. they actually use loops in their design

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What do you mean you don't want to use loops? You're going to have to iterate over it one way or another. Just take in each item individually and check if it's in `array2` as you go:

```
items = set(array2)
found = [i for i in array1 if i in items]
```

---

Furthermore, depending on how you are going to use the result, consider having a generator:

```
found = (i for i in array1 if i in array2)
```

so that you won't have to have the whole thing in memory all at once.

Comment: I mean I want to know if there is an efficient way to do this as I will be working with very large size arrays with timing restrictions..

Comment: @user32147: Why don't you specify the sizes of the arrays (more precisely than "over millions of values") and the timing restrictions?

Comment: @user32147 This is pretty efficient: You're not gonna get any faster than O(n). But see my edit anyway, I've made a small improvement to the answer.

Comment: you can use `set(array2)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Already mentioned that in the answer, but I'll make the point a bit better.

Answer (score 5):

There following will do it:

```
array1 = [1,4,4,7,10,10,10,15,16,17,18,20]
array2 = [4,6,7,8,9,10]
set2 = set(array2)
print [el for el in array1 if el in set2]
```

It keeps the order and repetitions of elements in `array1`.

It turns `array2` into a set for faster lookups. Note that this is only beneficial if `array2` is sufficiently large; if `array2` is small, it may be more performant to keep it as a list.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @Alex's answer, if you also want to extract the indices for each token, then here's how:

```
found = [[index,i] for index,i in enumerate(array1) if i in array2]
```