# How to add duplicates in intersection of two sets in python

Tags: python, set

Let suppose I have two sets

```
a = {1,2,3,4}
b = {2,2,5,7,3,3}
```

So when I take a intersection of these two sets , I also want duplicates in my result

```
c = a.intersection(b)
print (c)
{2,2,3,3}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the output you want?

Comment: `set` can't have duplicate items. after defining `b = {2,2,5,7,3,3}`  b will only contain `{2, 3, 5, 7}` better use `list`

Comment: What are the rules for how the number of times something appears in the output? Do you really want `2` appearing twice in the output, even though it only appears once in `a`?

Comment: If the answers below and the linked question don't cover your question adequately, please let me know, and I'll re-open your question.

Comment: @PM2Ring: This doesn't appear to be quite the same as the marked duplicate; that would give an intersection of `[2, 3]`, not `[2, 2, 3, 3]`. I'm still trying to figure out what the rules are that the OP is using here; it's not the usual multiset intersection.

Comment: @MarkDickinson If the OP clarifies, and they need something beyond the existing answers, I'm happy to re-open.

Comment: @PM2Ring the duplicate doesn't yield the same result. It keeps the smallest number of elements instead of the max number (I tried to change & to | but it doesn't do the same).   But yes, the inputs & outputs aren't clear.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Understood. But until the OP clarifies we don't need more answers from people guessing the actual requirements. ;)

Answer (score 3):

first if you define a set like this, you'll lose duplicate elements at once. So define lists instead:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,2,5,7,3,3]
```

Now my suggestion: count elements of the lists using `collections.Counter`, intersect & take max count, then expand the counter:

```
import collections

c1 = collections.Counter(a)
c2 = collections.Counter(b)

c3 = collections.Counter({k:max(c1[k],c2[k]) for k in set(a).intersection(b)})

print(list(c3.elements()))
```

result:

```
[2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @MohitSolanki, `set`s are not the right data structure for your use-case, because they cannot contain duplicates.
Thus, `b = {2,2,5,7,3,3}` will print `{2, 5, 7, 3}` if you access your variable `b` and this is likely not what you want.

May I suggest using `list`s? A possible solution might look like this:

```
def intersection(x: list, y: list):
    s = set(y)
    return [v for v in x if v in s]

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,2,5,7,3,3]
print(intersection(a, b))
print(intersection(b, a))


''' Output:
print(intersection(a, b)) -> [2, 3]
print(intersection(b, a)) -> [2, 2, 3, 3]
'''
```

Do you have questions in regards to my solution proposal? Also, please let me/us know if this answer is helpful to you! In case it is not, please provide me/us with more feedback. Cheers :-)

**EDIT** Incorporated the feedback from user @Jean-FrançoisFabre to improve the search complexity (imho by a constant → `O(n-c)` with `n=len(y)` and `c=len(y)-len(set(y))`) by introducing `s = set(y)` and performing a `v in s` in the `intersection` method. Thanks for pointing that out! This is in particular useful when the second argument contains A LOT of duplicates.

Comment: It's nice because it's simple. The only drawback is the linear search (`if v in y`). Also the last part (asking for questions) should be avoided. It's implicit that if people have remarks they comment.

Comment: improving your answer: `s = set(y); return [v for v in x if v in s]` now got rid of linear search

Comment: Nice catch @Jean-FrançoisFabre ! Thank you, I'll edit my post !

Answer (score 0):

A `set` cannot contain duplicates, that's sort of the point of them.

so to extend your code:

```
>>> a = {1,2,3,4}
>>> b = {2,2,5,7,3,3}
>>> a
{1, 2, 3, 4}
>>> b
{2, 3, 5, 7}
```

Note that the duplicates in `b` have been automatically removed by being part of a `set`.

So first you must re-define your variables `a` and `b` as lists:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,2,5,7,3,3]
```

Then I think your question is answered by: [Intersection of two lists including duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645053/intersection-of-two-lists-including-duplicates/37645155)

Comment: In such cases, flag as duplicates instead of providing a link. Well, the link you provided doesn't give the same result as OP wants.