# Fastest way to compare common items in two lists

Tags: python

I have two list like this:

```
listt = [["a","abc","zzz","xxx","abc","abc"],["yyy","ggg","abc","cccc"]]
```

I have another queryList like this:

```
queryList = ["abc","cccc","abc","yyy"]
```

`queryList` & `listt[0]` contain 2 `"abc"` in common.

`queryList` & `listt[1]` contain 1 `"abc"`, 1 `"cccc"` & 1 `"yyy"` in common.

So I want an output like this:

```
[2,3] #2 = Total common items between queryList & listt[0]
      #3 = Total common items between queryList & listt[1]
```

I am currently using loops to do this, but this seems to be slow. I will have millions of lists, with thousands of items per list.

```
listt = [["a","abc","zzz","xxx","abc","abc"],["yyy","ggg","abc","cccc"]]
queryList = ["abc","cccc","abc","yyy"]

totalMatch = []
for hashtree in listt:
    matches = 0
    tempQueryHash = queryList.copy()
    for hash in hashtree:
        for i in range(len(tempQueryHash)):
            if tempQueryHash[i]==hash:
                matches +=1
                tempQueryHash[i] = "" #Don't Match the same block twice.
                break

    totalMatch.append(matches)
print(totalMatch)
```

Comment: But `listt[0]` contains 3 `abc`. Should the output then be `[3, 3]`?

Comment: _millions of lists, with thousands of items per list_ If you have that much data, you might want to use something other than lists.  Lists must use sequential access to check if an item is present, which is very slow.  sets and dicts use hashing which is much faster.

Comment: That will be several gigabytes of data, so besides lists, you might also want to use something other than Python...

Comment: @mkrieger1  BUt query list only contains two "abc".So only two matches

Comment: Which format you recommand? @JohnGordon

dicts?

Comment: @Thomas My data is in MySQL....So I think maybe, I should find SQL solution, right? Damn...Dumb me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intersection of two lists including duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645053/intersection-of-two-lists-including-duplicates)

Comment: Well yes! A database is designed to solve such problems efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm still learning the ropes within Python. But according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37645155/9758194) older post on so, something like the following should work:

```
from collections import Counter
listt = [["a","abc","zzz","xxx","abc","abc"],["yyy","ggg","abc","cccc"]]
queryList = ["abc","cccc","abc","yyy"]
OutputList = [len(list((Counter(x) & Counter(queryList)).elements())) for x in listt]
# [2, 3]
```

I'll keep a lookout for some other method...

Comment: Thanks it's 2x faster

Comment: It's a pleasure. Don't forget to also thank the poster of the original content I implemented =) @Rahul. Link is included in the post.

Answer (score 2):

Improvement from [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61142368/8937335) answer.

Basically sum the values instead of counting the elements and also cache the queryListCounter.

```
from collections import Counter
listt = [["a","abc","zzz","xxx","abc","abc"],["yyy","ggg","abc","cccc"]]
queryList = ["abc","cccc","abc","yyy"]
queryListCounter = Counter(queryList)
OutputList = [sum((Counter(x) & queryListCounter).values()) for x in listt]
```

Comment: JvdV's answer is slightly faster, but you cache idea is good.

Comment: interesting, so `sum(aCounter.values())` is slower than `len(list(aCounter.elements()))`

Answer (score 0):

You can list the matches of listt and queryList and count the number of matches made.

```
output = ([i == z for i in listt[1] for z in queryList])
print(output.count(True))
```