# How to compare two column and count how many same items/string between in a dataframe them using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to compare two column and count how many same items/string between in a dataframe them using python?
for example:

```
row | column A | column B |
============================
 1  | ['NNP',  | ['NNP',  |
    |  'NNP',  | 'NNP',   |
    |  'NNP',  | 'VB',    |
    |  'NNP',  | 'NN',    |
    |  'CC',   | 'NN',    |
    |  'RB',   | 'Z']     |
    |  'NN',   |          |
    |  'Z',    |          |
2   | ['NNP',  | ['NNP',  |
    |  'VB',   |  'NN',   |
    |  'NN',   |  'VB']   |
    |  'NN',   |          |
    |  'Z']    |          |
```

what i want to get is:

```
   row | column A | column B |  count_same_string
    ==============================================
     1  | ['NNP',  | ['NNP',  | 4
        |  'NNP',  | 'NNP',   |
        |  'NNP',  | 'VB',    |
        |  'NNP',  | 'NN',    |
        |  'CC',   | 'NN',    |
        |  'RB',   | 'Z']     |
        |  'NN',   |          |
        |  'Z',    |          |
    2   | ['NNP',  | ['NNP',  |2
        |  'VB',   |  'NN',   |
        |  'NN',   |  'RB']   |
        |  'NN',   |          |
        |  'Z']    |          |
```

Comment: How you got the answer `4` in the first row? `VB` and `RB` are not supposed to be same??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645053/intersection-of-two-lists-including-duplicates) and retrieve the length using list comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({"column A":[["NNP","NNP","NNP","NNP","CC","RB","NN","Z"]],
                   "column B":[["NNP","NNP","VB","NN","NN","Z"]]})

df["result"] = [len(list((Counter(a) & Counter(b)).elements()))
                for a,b in zip(df["column A"], df["column B"])]

print (df)

                              column A                   column B  result
0  [NNP, NNP, NNP, NNP, CC, RB, NN, Z]  [NNP, NNP, VB, NN, NN, Z]       4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the following code.

```
df['count_same_string'] = df.apply(lambda row: len(set(row['column A']).intersection(row['column B'])))
```