# Intersection of Two Lists in Python

Tags: python, intersection

Is there a way I can calculate the Intersection of two lists that have duplicates in them. For example.

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,4,4,5]
list2=[4,4,5,5,6]
```

result would be:

```
[4,4,5]
```

I tried the intersection() function in pandas but that uses sets not lists

Comment: Also this: [Intersection of two lists including duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645053/intersection-of-two-lists-including-duplicates)

Comment: @TomKarzes: The one it was duped to was bad, but [Nathaniel Ford's duplicate, "Intersection of two lists including duplicates?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37645053/364696) is a perfect dupe (which I've added as the top duplicate).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, exactly as I said in my comment.  `collections.Counter` is clearly the simplest solution.