# How to find duplicate elements in two different arrays

Tags: kotlin

How do I find duplicate values in two different arrays ?

Pseudo-code:

```
array1["a", "b", "c", "d"]

array2["b", "d", "e", "f"]

duplicatesFound = findDuplicates(array1, array2) //will return ["b", "d"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intersection of two lists maintaining duplicate values in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53687530/intersection-of-two-lists-maintaining-duplicate-values-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 2):

obviously there is more than one way to solve it, here is one:
You can use [Intersect](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/intersect.html) between two `Iterable` arrays. for example

```
    val a1 = arrayListOf("a", "b", "c", "d")
    val a2 = arrayListOf("b", "d", "e", "f")

    val intersect = a2.intersect(a1)

    Log.d(TAG,intersect.toString()) // prints [b,d]
    Log.d(TAG,"${intersect.size}") // prints 2
```