# Intersection of list and dataframe, keeping duplicates of list but showing the values of a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, intersection

Found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663371/intersection-of-two-lists-keeping-duplicates-in-the-first-list) and my work is somewhat similar.

Say I have:

```
x = ['the', 'the', 'and', 'a', 'apple', 'heart', 'heart']
y = {'words': ['the', 'belt', 'computer', 'heart','and'],'values':[3,2,1,1,4]}
```

Using the suggestion in the link above, I got this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(y)
items = set(df['words'])

found = [i for i in x if i in items] 
print(found)
```

The result is:
['the', 'the', 'and', 'heart', 'heart']

I want to be able to get the corresponding value of the word and I am stuck. The result I want is this:

```
[3,3,4,1,1]
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve this? Would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need pandas. First rework your dictionary to have the words as keys, then use a comprehension:

```
y2 = dict(zip(*y.values()))
[y2[i] for i in x if i in y2]
```

Output: `[3,3,4,1,1]`

The (much less efficient) equivalent in pandas is:

```
s = df.set_index('words')['values']
pd.Series(x).map(s).dropna()
```

Output:

```
0    3.0
1    3.0
2    4.0
5    1.0
6    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks for this. my data is actually very large (in thousands). Is it more efficient to use dict rather than pandas?

Comment: Thousands is not huge, you can test both and compare. If using jupyter you can write `%%timeit` at the beginning of the cell to check the run length, if a script, there is the `timeit` module